# Mule Migration from 3.8.4 to 3.9.2 jars related issue

Tags: spring, migration, mule

Getting below issue while migration from 3.8.4 to 3.9.2 Mule runtime.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ResourceLoaderAware (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
```

I have spring spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar and all default jars in opt folder of Mule runtime.
ResourceLoaderAware class is in this spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar.

Any idea how do I resolve this issue.

```
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name '_muleNotificationManager': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '_muleTransactionManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.mule.api.transaction.TransactionManagerFactory org.mule.config.spring.factories.TransactionManagerFactoryBean.txManagerFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] for bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [CCModuleFlood-context.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ResourceLoaderAware (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
        at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.9.2.jar:3.9.2]
        at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.9.2.jar:3.9.2]
        at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.9.2.jar:3.9.2]
        at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.9.2.jar:3.9.2]
        at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.9.2.jar:3.9.2]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:210) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.2.jar:3.9.2]
        ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Error NoClassDefFoundError doesn't mean that it was not able to find the class, it means that there was some [previous error loading the class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756989/721855). You need to find the previous error to identify the root cause.

It might that there are some incompatible versions in the classpath that caused the original error.